# NaN remove from an Array. Underscorejs Javascript

Tags: underscore.js, nan

I have an array `[15,34,595,NaN]`.

How to remove "NaN" from an array?

Please give me the right direction on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [compact](http://underscorejs.org/#compact)

```
var arr = [15,34,595,NaN];
arr = _.compact(arr);
```

**NOTE:** Per documentation `compact` will also remove anything else that Javascript considers `falsy`

> false, null, 0, "", undefined and NaN

Comment: Worth mentioning the caveat that it will also remove all sorts of other things.

Comment: It's hard to understand why this would be the accepted answer, when it does much more, potentially unwanted, removals from your array, including removing zeroes. Please recall that the OP's question was *How to remove "NaN" from an array?*, not *How to remove "NaN" from an array, and it's OK to remove all kinds of other stuff as well?*.

Answer (score 3):

No real need for underscore here.

```
arr = arr.filter( (el) => !Number.isNaN( el ) );
```

Comment: I would like to use only underscore. Any idea?

Comment: @VikramSethumadhavan Underscore is a JS library. If I can use native JS constructs, why wouldn't I? Do you also want an underscore replacement for `if` or `function`?

Answer (score 2):

Reject elements which are NaN:

```
 _.reject(array, _.isNaN)
```